# Is {} == true or not in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain why in javascript,

`alert({} == true)`   shows *false*

`if ({}) alert('true')`   shows *true* ?

What's different in the if condition that changes the result?

I wanted to write some shorthand argument validator `obj || (obj = {});` and I was baffled by this discovery.

Comment: Is this on a specific browser? I tried it and I don't see `alert('true')` showing.

Comment: In Chrome 21 they both are false: http://jsfiddle.net/kq8QL/

Comment: So sorry guys, I mistyped the first time, I meant if ({}) alert('true'). You guys were so fast to reply!

Comment: An empty object is truthy, but not "equal" to `true` according to the semantics of the `==` operator.

Comment: With your edit, it is now something different entirely.  `if ({})` is equivalent to `if ({} != false)`, not `if ({} == true)`.  Which gives you, bizarrely, http://jsfiddle.net/kq8QL/1/.

Comment: `(obj || (obj = {})` will result in a `ReferenceError`. Use `(obj || {})`, or `(obj || (obj={},obj))`. And what's the relation of that to your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### `if ({}) alert('true')` -> `true`

`{}` is an object, which, when evaluated in the context of an `if` statement, gets coerced to a `Boolean`, and since `Boolean({})` evaluates to **`true`**, you get `if (true)`. This is documented in the ECMAScript specification, Section **[12.5 The if Statement](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.5)**:

> The production If Statement : if ( Expression ) Statement is evaluated
>   as follows:
>
> 1. Let exprRef be the result of evaluating Expression.
> 2. If **ToBoolean(GetValue(exprRef))** is false, return (normal, empty, empty).
> 3. Return the result of evaluating Statement.

### `alert({} == true)` -> `false`

This one is more tricky. From the [ECMAScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) specification, Section **[11.9.3 The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3)**:

> The comparison x == y, where x and y are values, produces true or false. Such a comparison is performed as follows:
>
> If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison **x == ToNumber(y)**.

Thus, `{} == true` will be evaluated as `{} == Number(true)`, which is evaluated to `{} == 1`, which is **`false`**.

This is also why `1 == true` evaluates to `true`, but `2 == true` evaluates to `false`.

Answer (score 2):

`{}` is not `true` so it won't show up in your first example. In your second example `{}` is not false so it will pass the test.

Like my teacher used to say, you can't compare potatoes and carrots.

It's not only with arrays, it will work with anything:

```
alert(3 == true); // shows false

if (3) alert('true'); // shows true
```

Comment: So you're saying that `if(exp) statement` actually means 'if exp is not false then exp' ?

Comment: Essentially yes. Except for a few _values_ that will evaluate as false, such as `null` or `undefined` for instance. Or `1` will evaluate as `true`, because it can be converted to a boolean `true`.

Answer (score 2):

In boolean operations, generally anything that is not `0` evaluates to true. 
http://jsfiddle.net/QF8GW/

```
if (0) console.log("0 shows true"); // does not log a value
if (-1) console.log("-1 shows true");
if (12345) console.log("12345 shows true");
if ({}) console.log("{} shows true");
if ([]) console.log("[] shows true");
```

All of these except `0` will evaluate to true.

However, their values, when compared to `true` will not evaluate to `true`.

```
// logs the statement (1 and true are the same.)
​if (1 == true) console.log("1==true shows true");​​​​​​​​

if (12345 == true) console.log("12345==true shows true"); // does not log
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alert({} == true) //display "false"

if({} == true)
{
   alert("it's true");
}else
{
   alert("it's false"); // <-- alert this
}
```

[( snippet )](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8tfb/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried in [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/atiruz/rjH39/2/) and only try in the first alert says false, the IF does not alert true.